# QuickBooks Integration: Can't sync data into QBO

Tags: java, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to integrate an accounting system with QBO. I have everything working except the part that syncs invoices into QBO. I'm getting the following errors:

```
"ERROR CODE: 3200 " and statusCode=401.
```

I searched on the documentation and

```
 Error code 3200 is "outdated edit sequence", and statuscode 401 is for "Authentication Failed".
```

I only have the token for 1 month. I don't think it's expired.

Here is the error log:

------ Query for Select * from invoice -----

```
SELECT * FROM Invoice ORDERBY DocNumber  


2014-12-14 10:54:43.700  INFO 4936 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] com.intuit.logger                        : HttpResponse content-type (deserialization format) : xml
2014-12-14 10:54:44.478 ERROR 4936 --- [nio-9001-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intuit.ipp.exception.AuthenticationException: ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR MESSAGE:message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:SignatureBaseString: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F1292716660%2Fquery&minorversion%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdTJo1L1OpyrtEENk28kIl7lQGY%26oauth_nonce%3D5531296139710727189%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1418572482%26oauth_token%3DlvprdDaJWaGXoNB3KguFCef9s2GbjrMhnVjmICrLQiCQpZCJ%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26query%3DSELECT%2520%252A%2520FROM%2520Invoice%2520ORDERBY%2520DocNumber%26requestid%3D4b5f973c47b446a7ba4d0918eec9f5f3
] with root cause

com.intuit.ipp.exception.AuthenticationException: ERROR CODE:3200, ERROR MESSAGE:message=ApplicationAuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401, ERROR DETAIL:SignatureBaseString: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com%2Fv3%2Fcompany%2F1292716660%2Fquery&minorversion%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3DqyprdTJo1L1OpyrtEENk28kIl7lQGY%26oauth_nonce%3D5531296139710727189%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1418572482%26oauth_token%3DlvprdDaJWaGXoNB3KguFCef9s2GbjrMhnVjmICrLQiCQpZCJ%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26query%3DSELECT%2520%252A%2520FROM%2520Invoice%2520ORDERBY%2520DocNumber%26requestid%3D4b5f973c47b446a7ba4d0918eec9f5f3

at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.HandleResponseInterceptor.execute(HandleResponseInterceptor.java:91)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeResponseInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:94)
at com.intuit.ipp.interceptors.IntuitInterceptorProvider.executeInterceptors(IntuitInterceptorProvider.java:67)
at com.intuit.ipp.services.DataService.executeQuery(DataService.java:323)
at com.intuit.developer.sampleapp.ecommerce.qbo.QBOGateway.determineInvoicesToPushAndSave(QBOGateway.java:150)
at com.intuit.developer.sampleapp.ecommerce.qbo.QBOGateway.createInvoicesInQBO(QBOGateway.java:123)
at com.intuit.developer.sampleapp.ecommerce.controllers.SyncRequestController.createSyncRequest(SyncRequestController.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1720)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Its very clear that you are failing to authenticate from the http response and message in stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

As error message suggests this is an authentication issue.

It comes because of any of the following issue.

1. OAuth tokens are not correct
2. OAuth tokens are expired.
3. You're not passing the correct content-type

In this case, as it is a GET query, so chances are it is failing because of any of the first two issue.

You can generate accessToken and accessSecret using the OAuthPlayground tool. https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

PN - After completing C2QB(OAuth) flow, you should use 'App Menu API Test.' option which will show you accessToken and accessSecret.

Answer (score 0):

add `Bearer` or `basic`

```
   'Authorization': 'Bearer AB11588770007gXsEtCmJfNsyIpquocg2k2tXmUoeCrw5I0YIASACSHHHHHDSDSDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'
```